# Iterate thru all folders at the current path where the script resides

Tags: powershell

I have a script called fetch-all.ps1. I want to iterate thru all the folders on the same level as where my script resides and perform a git fetch. This is what I got

```
cls
cd C:\dev
$folders  = Get-ChildItem -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Force -Directory | Select-Object Name

foreach($folder in $folders)
{
 Write-Host "Fetching from:" $folder.Name;
 #cd $folder.Name
 #git fetch
 #cd ..
 Write-Host "Done." 
}
```

I have commented out the parts that will not work because right now all I get in that loop is the script's file name. This is the output

```
Fetching from: fetch-all.ps1 
Done.
```

What I want is an output like so..

```
Fetching from: Folder1
Done.
Fetching from: Folder2
Done.
Fetching from: Folder3
Done.
Fetching from: Folder4
Done.
```

If I am able to get those folders which are the same level as my script then I can `cd` into it and execute a git fetch. Any idea what is going wrong with my script?

Comment: Variable `$PSScriptRoot` will point to the path that the script file is located.

Comment: @Daniel if you add your comment as an answer then I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you are writing is a script to iterate through a directory that contains git repos.  I wrote a script to do this which allows you to issue various commands in each directory.

Usage:

`Start-ForAllRepos -Cmd 'git status'`  << default command if -Cmd not passed

`Start-ForAllRepos -Cmd 'git pull'`

I put this function in my PowerShell profile.ps1.
See `about_profiles`
[about_profiles on microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1)

CODE:

```
function global:Start-ForAllRepos
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [string]
        $Cmd = 'git status',

        [Parameter(Position=1)]
        [string[]]
        $RepoRoot = @(
            'd:\git'
            ),

        [switch]
        $Wait
    )

    $currentLocation = Get-Location

    foreach ($root in $RepoRoot)
    {
        Set-Location $root

        Get-ChildItem -Directory -Exclude '.vscode' | 
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | 
            ForEach-Object {
                # check if this is a git repo
                if (-not (Test-Path (Join-Path $_ '.git')))
                {
                    #"Not a git repo $($_)"
                    continue;
                }

                "-"*72
                $_
                $Cmd
                "-"*72
                Set-Location $_
                cmd.exe /c $Cmd

                # wait when requested
                if ($Wait) {
                    $null = Read-Host -Prompt "Press enter to continue..."
                }
            }

            Set-Location $root
        }
    Set-Location $currentLocation
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is more that what I needed. The comment by Daniel solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The $PSScriptRoot variable will point to the path where the script file is located.